# How do I make a node package with an optional peerDependency that it directly it depends on in test code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

[The official documentation for peerDependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies)'s says (emphasis mine):

> A plugin package is meant to be used with another "host" package, even though it does not *always* directly use the host package.

I've got a situation where my plugin *does* use the host package directly (in a test), even though this `peerDependency` is meant to be optional for the app. This is the relationship I want between these packages:

```
App --may depend on, but may not--> canvas
My package --optional peer dependency--> canvas
My package tests --depends on--> canvas
```

How should my `package.json` be written for this? Here's what I've currently got, and I think it works?

```json
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "canvas": {
      "optional": true
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to write a `package.json` with an optional `peerDependency` that it uses in test code?

Comment: We should NOT publish devDependencies and test files to npm.

Comment: @AhmetEmrebas I wasn't planning to

Comment: I am just curious about the case. Does your package behaves differently with and without canvas? Optional peer dependencies do not make sense to me. Are you providing multiple implementations? If yes, why don't you write an interface that compatible with Canvas or any other packages alike? Just curious why do we need optional peer dependency? Thank you.

Comment: `Does your package behaves differently with and without canvas` Indirectly, yes. My library is for jsdom and jsdom uses canvas that way.

Comment: I just checked jsdom already provides canvas in peerDependency ( https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/main/package.json  )? Do we need to provide it again?

Comment: @AhmetEmrebas `Do we need to provide it again?` That's a great question. I have no idea and I don't know if there is any official documentation on the matter.

Comment: @AhmetEmrebas [I asked your question in a separate SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78150096/are-package-json-peerdependencies-transitive).