# Are package.json peerDependencies transitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I'll ask my question in the form of an example. Let's assume there is a long dependency chain:

```
A --depends on--> B
A --depends on--> E
B --depends on--> C
C --depends on--> D
D --peer dependency on--> E
```

- `B` and `C` don't use `E`.

Here's the question: should `B` and `C`'s `package.json` specify a `peerDependency` on `E` (the same `peerDependency` found in `D`'s `package.json`)?

---

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78144589/how-do-i-make-a-node-package-with-an-optional-peerdependency-it-depends-on-in-te) inspired my question:

> I just checked jsdom already provides canvas in peerDependency ( https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/main/package.json  )? Do we need to provide it again?

Comment: The rule is a pretty straight-forward "if _your_ code does not have additional functionality that is unlocked by a peer dependency being available, it doesn't have a peer dependency". So no, if B and C don't do anything with E, they should absolutely not list E as a peer dependency.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That rule seems straightforward if you've just got two packages in the chain. But imagine running `npm install` on `B` in my example. How will `npm` know it's okay for `E` to be missing?

Comment: E is not "missing". In fact, peer dependencies are never missing because they're never _required_. They are instead optional modules that _can_ be installed (by you, based on your own code needs), and if they are, a project whose peer dependencies have been met will be able to "do a little more". For example: JSDom does not need canvas installed to do its job as a DOM parser. But if you _do_ have `canvas` installed, that will let JSDom do a little more. So: `B` does not need `E` for anything (it will never "do a little more" if E _is_ installed) and `npm` doesn't need to care.

Comment: (If a package has a peer dependency, then _you_ get to decide whether or not to list that dependency as a _real_ dependency in your own package.json, because _your_ code relies on that extended functionality being enabled. E.g. if your code relies on JSDom (no matter how deep) having canvas functionality, then you should add `canvas` as a normal dependency for your project, because _your_ code relies on what that "unlocks")

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `peer dependencies are never missing because they're never required` I have evidence that contradicts this, but I suspect it's a misinterpretation on my part.  Can you explain why 1) [the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies#the-solution-peer-dependencies) says, "I only work when plugged in to version 1.2.x of my host package, so if you install me, *be sure* that it's alongside a compatible host." 2) JSDOM also has `peerDependenciesMeta.canvas.optional=true`. Why does this even exist if `peerDependencies` are always optional?

Comment: (1) Because semver still applies. If I write a package with a peer dependency for ReactDOM v15, and your project uses both my package, _and_ ReactDOM v18, we're going to have a bad time, because my code doesn't _need_ ReactDOM, but if it's there, it better be v15. I didn't keep up with React, and you did: now choices need to be made. (2) Ask the JSDom folks? In CJS you can try/catch a require to check whether your peer dependency is available, and in ESM you can try-await/catch or then().catch() the dynamic import to do the same, so that's something only the JSDom devs can answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 2) was merely an example. Here was my point: Why would [`peerDependenciesMeta.<package>.optional`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependenciesmeta) exist if peerDependencies are never required? I suppose I'm assuming "required" is mutually exclusive with "optional." Are you not?

Comment: I am not. Peer dependencies are never required, but remember that `npm` is here to _help you manage your code_ and so it is incredibly useful for it to warn about the fact that a package will be able to do more if you have its peer dependencies installed. Because while a package never needs peer dependencies to do its core job, _you_ may need the functionality that is only offered when the peer dependencies are installed. So `npm` will warn you about the fact that _your_ project may need more dependencies (remember: it's a warning, not an error. Nothing is "wrong", you're getting a heads up)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Okay now I understand what you mean, but unless you can point to a resource backing your claims, I respectfully disagree with some of your statements. 1) "Optional" and "required" are definitionally mutually exclusive. 2) `peerDependencies` *can* be for optional functionality, but they can also be for required functionality. Examples of the latter can be found in the official documentation.

Comment: I don't see a single example in the docs where the peer dependency is required. Can you point one out, please? Because the whole _point_ of peer dependencies (the reason the category got added) is to mark optional, bolt-on functionality (originally: plugins. These days: a lot of other optional-to-the-package, not-necessarily-optional-to-you functionality too).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm going to turn your question around: Can you find me one example in the docs where peer dependencies are optional (excluding the peerDependenciesMeta section)? `the whole point of peer dependencies (the reason the category got added) is to mark optional, bolt-on functionality` I'm going to have to disagree with this too. Peer deps were created so plugins could specify that they 1) *need* another package even if they don't necessarily use it 2) want the "host" environment to define the specific version of that package so the host and the plugin share it when running.

Comment: Fair enough. SO is signalling that this is now an extended discussion, so I guess we've gone back and forth enough that I'm not helping your question get answered at this point, and hopefully someone else can come along with a fresh take.